# Handle behavior of CONFIRM event for SelectDialogBox

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a list of records. To display the list, I am using sap.m.SelectDialog:

```
<SelectDialog id="idSelDgAddSupervisor" confirm="handleConfirm" growingThreshold="2000" growing="true" showClearButton="true"
        items="{items}" multiSelect="true"
        liveChange="handleSearch" title="{i18n>Choose}"
         autoAdjustWidth="true" growingScrollToLoad="true">
        <StandardListItem id="idItem" description="{Name}"
            iconDensityAware="false" iconInset="false"
            title="{Plant}" type="Active"/>
    </SelectDialog>
```

[image]

On top of this, I have put a "warning" message box in handleConfirm() function, if user selects more than one entry. Something like this:

[image]

**WHAT IS HAPPENING RIGHT NOW**
When user selects more that one entry, it shows the warning message, **BUT** it closes the selection popover before it shows popover.

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE**
When user clicks on "OK" button in warning message, it should go back to entry selection screen, and selection popover should not close until user selects ONLY one entry.

Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your code for the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this. What I did was, in onClose event of dialog, I destroyed the id of dialog, and reopened the same dialog after destroying the id (so as to save my code from generating "duplicated element id" error).

Answer (score -1):

I think selectDialog auto-Close.

You can now bypass that by setting a Select into a Dialog that you'll be able to open and close on event.

By the same way, i understand that your user can choose ONLY ONE  entry, so why multiSelect is true ? if you set it at false, only one entry will be selected and no need to put a warning dialog.